# I want to point my custom created color palette to default color palette in Tableau

Tags: database, tableau-api, data-analysis, extension-methods, tableau-desktop

When I open the workbook and create the new sheet then the color palette which is assign to the Automatic is generate automatically. Now I have created the custom color palette using the preferences folder. Now I have to assign this new custom palette as a default and wanted to assign it to the Automatic parameter. so that whenever the user start to build the new sheet then instantly my custom color palette should be populated instead of selecting manually.

Can you all help me out for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the XML color palette without name attribute. Than it will be work the the way you want.

Here is the e.g. XML Code.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<workbook>
    <preferences>
        <color-palette type="ordered-sequential">
          <color>#eb912b</color>
          <color>#eb9c42</color>
          <color>#ebad67</color>
          <color>#eabb86</color>
          <color>#eacba8</color>
          <color>#ebd8c2</color>
        </color-palette>
    </preferences>
</workbook>
```